# riddle: "On the Earth I am dead, / Though I live on the Moon..."

Tags: riddle, word

A rhyming riddle:

> On the Earth I am dead,
> Though I live on the Moon.
> I am in no crater,
> And I'm in every boom.
> What am I?

What is the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit trivial but you could be

> the letter O

which

> doesn't appear in "Earth" but is present in "Moon", "no crater" and "boom"